# How to configure windsor for passing dependency as argument through dependency tree?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have following component composition:

```
public interface IJob {
    ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}

public class JobC : IJob
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    private ServiceA serviceA;
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public JobC(ServiceA serviceA, ServiceB serviceB)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        this.serviceB = serviceB;
    }
}

public class ServiceB
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceA
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, there's Logger property all around. Thing is, that I need to pass that property value during resolving (different jobs are requiring different configuration loggers).
So if only top component would need this, it would be as simple as

```
var childLogger = Logger.CreateChildLogger(jobGroupName);
var job = windsorContainer.Resolve(jobType);
job.Logger = childLogger;
```

But I need to pass childLogger down the tree and that tree is quite complex, I don't wish to manually pass logger instance to each component, which needs it, wondering if Windsor could help me at this?

Update: May be this will help better understand problem:
In [wiki](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Passing-Arguments.ashx) there's notice:

> Inline dependencies don't get propagated
>   Whatever arguments you pass to Resolve method will only be available to the root component
>   you're trying to resolve, and its Interceptors. All the components further down (root's 
>   dependencies, and their dependencies and so on) will not have access to them.

Why is it like so and is there any workaround?

Update 2:
May be it will help, if I'll add real situation.

So, we have Application, which sends/receives data from/to various sales channels. Each sales channel has corresponding collection of jobs, like send updated product information, receive orders, etc (each job may contain smaller jobs inside). So it is logical, that we need to keep each channel's log information separate from other channel's, but single channel's jobs logs should go to single listener, that we could see sequence of what is happening (if each job and subjob would have own logging listener, we would need to merge logs by time to understand what is going on). Some channels and their job sets are not known at compile time (let's say there's channel A, we can start separate channel for a specific country by simple adding that country to DB, depending on load we can switch synchronization method, etc.).

What all that means, that we may have UpdateProductsForChannelAJob, which will be used in two  different channels (ChannelA US and ChannelA UK), so it's logger will depend on which channel it depends to.

So what we are doing now, is we create child logger for each channel and we pass it when resolving Job instance as a parameter. That works, but has one annoying thing - we have to pass logger instance manually inside job to each dependency (and dependencies dependency), that may be logging something.

Update 3:

I've found in Windsor documentation feature, that sounds like what I need:

> There are times where you need to supply a dependency, which will not be known until the creation time of the component.  For example, say you need a creation timestamp for your service. You know how to obtain it at the time of registration, but you don't know what its specific value will be (and indeed it will be different each time you create a new instance). In this scenarios you use DynamicParameters method.

And you get two parameters in DynamicParameters delegate, one of them is dictionary and

> It is that dictionary that you can now populate with dependencies which will be passed further to the resolution pipeline

Given that, I thought this will work:

```
public interface IService
{
}

public class ServiceWithLogger : IService
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceComposition
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public IService Service { get; set; }

    public ServiceComposition(IService service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }
} 

public class NameService
{
    public NameService(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NameServiceConsumer
{       
    public NameService NameService { get; set; }
}

public class NameServiceConsumerComposition
{       
    public NameService NameService { get; set; }
    public NameServiceConsumer NameServiceConsumer { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void GivenDynamicParamtersConfigurationContainerShouldPassLoggerDownTheTree()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<ServiceWithLogger>().LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<ServiceComposition>().DynamicParameters((k, d) =>
            {
                d["Logger"] = k.Resolve<ILogger>().CreateChildLogger(d["name"].ToString());
            }).LifestyleTransient()
            );

        var service = container.Resolve<ServiceComposition>(new { name = "my child" });
        var childLogger = ((ServiceWithLogger) service.Service).Logger;
        Assert.IsTrue(((ConsoleLogger)childLogger).Name.Contains("my child"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void GivenDynamicParamtersConfigurationContainerShouldPassNameDownTheTree()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>();
        container.Register(
            Component.For<NameService>().LifestyleTransient().DependsOn(new {name = "default"}),
            Component.For<NameServiceConsumer>().LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<NameServiceConsumerComposition>().DynamicParameters((k, d) =>
            {
                d["nameService"] = k.Resolve<NameService>(d["nameParam"]);
            }).LifestyleTransient()
            );

        var service = container.Resolve<NameServiceConsumerComposition>(new { nameParam = "my child" });
        Console.WriteLine(service.NameServiceConsumer.NameService.Name);
        Assert.IsTrue(service.NameServiceConsumer.NameService.Name.Contains("my child"));
    }
}
```

But it does not.

Comment: Re "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources." I don't mean to brag or preclude other answers, but I'm currently the top answerer for the castle-windsor tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/castle-windsor/topusers and member of the Castle team: http://castleproject.org/community/team.html

Comment: Mauricio, I have no doubt about your knowledge (actually I'm using solrnet and it's a superb library), what I meant, that I'm sure that there should be solution or at least clear explanation what I'm doing wrong. Your answer is oriented to specifically ILogger, but my question is how do I pass concrete instance at resolving moment to composition. Sorry if that looked like I don't think you're credible or smth. I've updated question with part that puzzles me most.

Comment: Ah, it's more clear now. The reason it's like that is because you're not really supposed to pass deep inline dependencies to Resolve. You should register your components and let Windsor manage them. Question is, why can't you want to register your components? Also, if this is not about logging, please use a more appropriate analogy (or just present your concrete case).

Comment: Can you give us any more information about your problem? Or were you able to solve it?

Comment: Updated question with example, haven't solved it yet.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are calling Resolve() in your code. Why? You should let Windsor resolve dependencies as much as possible.

Comment: On timer event I check if I need to start any job, and if yes, I need to create it's instance by knowing job instance type to create and group name it belongs to. After creating instance, I start it running in background thread, after finishing release it, so not sure if there's any way not to use Resolve in this case.

Comment: We thought about that, checked your code on QuartzNetIntegration and there is WindsorJobFactory, which uses kernel.Resolve for resolving job instance, so problem would be the same - how to configure logging for separate job groups to log into separate logs. May be we're looking not at the right place, may be we should think how to configure log4net right, not the IoC.

Comment: right, but I'd still look into customizing the logging facility (if this is about logging, which I'm now confused about)

Comment: Well, at first I did not wished to limit my question to logging, then I've updated it with more specific example, so it was about logging, and now I've updated it once again.

Comment: ok, my recommendation is still to take a look at the logging facility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally got the aha moment why this is relatively easy to implement, but is not implemented in Windsor (and I think any other container).
Let's say we have following configuration:

```
public class TransientA
{
    public SingletonC SingletonC { get; set; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}

public class TransientB
{
    public SingletonC SingletonC { get; set; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}

public class SingletonC
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}
```

class names reflect their lifestyles, so if you would do recursive property injection on Resolve for TransientA, you would change TransientB.SingletonC.Logger property also!

You could skip singletons property injection on propagation, but that a) would add confusion b) would not solve initial problem anyway (some of the logging would go to singlenton's logger).

So in case to use recursive property injection you would need to add limitation, that component should not have singleton dependencies (PerWebRequest/PerThread also) in it's dependency hierarchy, which is quite limiting.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass your logger manually after resolving. Let Windsor do it for you. Use the [logging facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx).

Comment: Thing is, that what instance of logger to pass depends on group, to which job is assigned, and I think logging facility can only inject value, that was known during registration, if not, could you provide an example?

Comment: @Giedrius : sorry, I don't understand the question. The logging facility will pass an appropriate logger to each component, with an appropriate logger name to identify the component in the logs. What isn't known at registration time?

Comment: I think I need to look at logging facility sources to understand how it works, because right now I don't see how it could pass right logger name at registration (I mean I don't need each component of JobC to have own logger name, even JobC should not have own logger name, it should carry group name, jobs are groupped into groups at runtime and each group of jobs have own logging listener).

Comment: @Giedrius : if you need to customize the logger and add the group name to the logger name, then yes, I'd try customizing the logging facility...